# How to access individual predictions in Spark RandomForest?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

I wish to use pyspark.mllib.tree.RandomForest module to get a proximity matrix for my observations.

Until now, my data was small enough to be loaded directly into memory. I therefore used sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier to get the proximity matrix in the following way: suppose X is a matrix that contains the features and Y is a vector that contains the labels. I trained the random forest to distinguish between objects with label "0" and label "1". Having the trained random forest, I wanted to get a measure of proximity between every pair of observations in my dataset by counting in how many decision trees the two observations have got the same final node (=leaf). So, for 100 decision trees, the proximity measure between two observation can range from 0 (never fall in the same final leaf) and 100 (have fallen to the same final leaf in all the decision trees). The python implementation of this:

```
import numpy
from sklearn import ensemble

## data
print X.shape, Y.shape # X is a matrix that holds the 4281 features and contains 8562 observations and Y contains 8562 labels
>> (8562, 4281) (8562,)

## train the tree
n_trees = 100
rand_tree = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n_tress)
rand_tree.fit(X, Y)

## get proximity matrix
apply_mat = rand_tree.apply(X)
obs_num = len(apply_mat)
sim_mat = numpy.eye(obs_num) * len(apply_mat[0]) # max values that they can be similar at = N estimators

for i in xrange(obs_num):
    for j in xrange(i, obs_num):
        vec_i = apply_mat[i]
        vec_j = apply_mat[j]
        sim_val = len(vec_i[vec_i==vec_j])
        sim_mat[i][j] = sim_val
        sim_mat[j][i] = sim_val

sim_mat_norm = sim_mat / len(apply_mat[0])
print sim_mat_norm.shape
>> (8562, 8562)
```

Now, I work with data that is too big to fit into the memory and therefore I decided to work with Spark instead. I am able to load the data and fit it but I did not find a way to "apply" the random forest to the data in order to get the proximity matrix. Is there any way to get it?
(I use the same implementation as in the Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-ensembles.html#classification):

```
from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils

# Load and parse the data file into an RDD of LabeledPoint.
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, 'data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt')
# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                 numTrees=3, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                 impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)
```

I will also be happy to hear other ideas that can solve my problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PySpark MLlib model doesn't provide a direct way to access this information. Theoretically you can try to extract the models directly and predict individually for each tree:

```
from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTreeMode

numTrees = 3
trees = [DecisionTreeModel(model._java_model.trees()[i])
    for i in range(numTrees)]

predictions = [t.predict(testData) for t in trees]
```

But it is probably better to use ML model instead:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier

df = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexed").fit(df)
df_indexed = indexer.transform(df)

model = RandomForestClassifier(
    numTrees=3, maxDepth=2, labelCol="indexed", seed=42
).fit(df_indexed)
```

and use `rawPrediction` or `probability` columns:

```
model.transform(df).select("rawPrediction", "probability").show(5, False)

## +---------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
## |rawPrediction                          |probability                              |
## +---------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
## |[0.0,3.0]                              |[0.0,1.0]                                |
## |[2.979591836734694,0.02040816326530612]|[0.9931972789115647,0.006802721088435374]|
## |[2.979591836734694,0.02040816326530612]|[0.9931972789115647,0.006802721088435374]|
## |[2.979591836734694,0.02040816326530612]|[0.9931972789115647,0.006802721088435374]|
## |[2.979591836734694,0.02040816326530612]|[0.9931972789115647,0.006802721088435374]|
## +---------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

**Note**: If you think that your data requires Spark then building full distance / similarity matrix is unlikely to be a good idea. Just saying.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you think that it is not a good idea because my data is large? I actually need to find the ~1% percent of the closest objects pairs from my ~30M objects (therefore I wanted to calculated the proximity matrix). The objects have lots of features (4000) therefore I decided to do this with RF + distance matrix rather than with KDE or other algorithms, due to its natural parallelisation. Regrading your first suggestion - can I still parallelise the predictions vector in the Spark framework?

Comment: `t.predict(testData)` is distributed but you cannot distribute outer loop (i.e. comprehension). It means you need `numTrees` jobs.

Comment: Regarding full similarity matrix its is exactly about the size. You can try to apply some approximations though and compare only the best candidates.

Comment: There is for example https://github.com/soundcloud/cosine-lsh-join-spark but it has no Python API.

Comment: I will look into that and compare its results to what I get so far. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi @dbaron I have exactly the same problem. I'm trying to get the proximity matrix with Pypsark. Did you finally got it? Do you think is it worth using spark?